# Facet Blocks are not appearing in indexed views

Tags: views, search

I have created Index with apache solr server using search API.

Created a view using that index in page display and facets are appearing as rendered in side bar.

Now I Created another block display in the same view but now the facets are not displaying in the block display.

What would be the problem with block display and facets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was... I rendered that block in sidebar region.. That was it..

When your search isn't the main content on the page then the facets does not appear now I rendered the block view it in **Content Region**.

Now the facets appear!!!